# Use jQuery to find all images on a (different) page via ajax for preloading

Tags: jquery, ajax, preload, image-preloader

I'm building a app - converted from flash to html/js and using jQuery. Pages/scenes are pulled in via ajax and I have a 'loading' overlay in place until these are loaded however in addition I want to preload images for the next and previous pages.

So I pull in page-5.php via ajax then I need to preload the images in the background for pages 4/6 to speed things up for the user.

I have a preload function I can insert an array of images into - the tricky bit is using ajax to find the src of all images on page-6.php for example.

So I need a call to:
- find all images on page-6.php, grab their src's into an array. 
possible?

I guess I could hide an array on each page containing the images and grab this but I'd rather keep it all dynamic.

Any thoughts / help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to parse the html response with regular jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   url:[your url],
   success: function(data) {
       $("img", data).each(function() {
           alert($(this).attr("src");
       });
   }
});
```

EDIT:

```
            $.ajax({
               url: 'http://localhost:8888/site/scenarios/scenario-1.php',
               success: function(data) {
                   $("img", data).each(function() {
                      alert( $(this).attr("src") );
                   });
               }
            });
```

Comment: There were a couple of errors (missing open and closing brackets) in your code but once fixed that works a treat for retrieving the image src's. Thank you!

    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://localhost:8888/site/scenarios/scenario-1.php',
       success: function(data) {
           $("img", data).each(function() {
              alert( $(this).attr("src") );
           });
       }
    });

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to preload the next/prev page in a two hidden div on the same page, which is not shown until selected. That way you don't have to do any parsing/loading from your side, as the browser will handle it nicely.

[Here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/simple-tabs-with-ajax-and-jquery/) is an example on how to use ajax to load a tab, but in your case you would need to prefetch the left and right div, instead of loading it when clicked.

Comment: Thanks - I figured that could be a way around it but want to keep this as clean as possibly, there's a lot already going on so wanted to avoid loading into hidden div's etc.